# Trying to send an HTTP POST request on an "add to cart" form

Tags: c#, http, http-headers

This might be an odd question, but I'm ultimately trying to click an "add to cart" button by sending a POST request in C#. I'm currently using Advanced REST Client to try to send the request and I'm having a lot trouble. [This is the item I'm trying to add to cart](http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/bags/jndyx5az6/black). I am sending the POST request with

> http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/169720/add?authenticity_token=oZ2ZwxDZwEJ%2BUSczNZrhUlNSGw5NnsP%2FvcbxiSnxnSM%3D&commit=add%20to%20cart&size=32377&utf8=%E2%9C%93

but I keep getting 404 not found. I might be putting in the wrong information into the client. I just started learning about POST/GET requests yesterday, so any advice would be greatly appreciated; thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to get content using POST request.

```
public static async Task<byte[]> GetPostContentAsync(string url, string data)
{
    var content = new MemoryStream();
    var cookies = new CookieContainer();

    HttpWebRequest webReq;

    webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    webReq.CookieContainer = cookies;
    webReq.Method = "POST";
    webReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    Stream requestStream = await webReq.GetRequestStreamAsync();

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
    {
        await writer.WriteAsync(data);
    }

    using (var responseStream = await webReq.GetResponseAsync())
    {
        using (Stream response = responseStream.GetResponseStream())
        {
            await response.CopyToAsync(content);
        }
    }

    return content.ToArray();
}
```